swagger-ui-express unnecessary parameter showing
I am using swagger-ui-express with swagger-autogen with the below configurations, but the req.headers.Authorization is showing as a parameter on the routes that has verifyJWT middleware and as my understanding it should not be there because once you login and get the token and authorize yourself with the token on the Authorize box, you should be able to access all the routes with out any problem, correct me if I'm wrong.
swagger.js
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')();

const docs = {
    info: {
        // title: "My API",
        description: "Documentation",
    },
    host: "localhost:3000",
    schemes: ['http', 'https'],
    securityDefinitions: {
        bearerAuth: {
            type: 'apiKey', // Set this to apiKey since JWT is typically used as an API key.
            name: 'Authorization', // Set this to "Authorization" as this is the standard header name for JWT authorization.
            in: 'header',   // Set this to "header" as JWT tokens are typically passed in the Authorization header.
            description: "Enter JWT token in the format: Bearer < JWT token here >" // This provides a clear explanation for developers on how to use the JWT token in the Authorization header.
        },
    },      
    // adds security on every route
    security: [{ bearerAuth: [] }], 
}


const outputFile = "./swagger-output.json";
const routes = ['./server.js'];

swaggerAutogen(outputFile, routes, docs).then(() => {
    require("./server")
});


verifyJWT.js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const verfiyJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  // const authHeader = req.headers.authorization || req.headers.Authorization;
  if (!authHeader?.startsWith("Bearer ")) return res.sendStatus(401);
  console.log(authHeader); // Bearer token
  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403); // invalid token(forbidden)
    req.user = decoded.userInfo.username;
    req.roles = decoded.userInfo.roles;
    next();
  });
};

module.exports = verfiyJWT;


server.js  app.use('/users', verifyJWT, require('./routes/api/users') // #swagger.tags = ['Users']  ); 
